# Spring integration chain resolver service activator method

Tags: spring, spring-integration

```
<int:chain input-channel="request" output-channel="response">

    <int:service-activator  method="create" ref="ServiceImpl" />
    <int:service-activator  method="update" ref="ServiceImpl" />
    <int:service-activator  method="cancel" ref="ServiceImpl" />

</int:chain>
```

So I'am learning spring integration, and ran into problem how to resolve which service method to call? I tried to use router and used expression:

```
  <int:router input-channel="inputChannel" expression="payload.type">
    <int:mapping value="CREATE" channel="create"/>
    <int:mapping value="UPDATE" channel="update"/>
    <int:mapping value="CANCEL" channel="cancel"/>
</int:router>
```

Maybe there is a way to solve it into chain?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not clear what you are asking. The `router` is like an `if...else` to determine the next processing step according incoming data. The `chain` is like a public API which may call several methods: the next one is going to be called after the previous. Your `how to resolve which service method to call` somehow is not related to the chain at all. The router part is good one, but chain doesn't have any dynamic resolutions